# Algolia search for array that contains value

Tags: algolia

I am using Algolia search, and right now I use this to find a specific item by id:

```
algolia.getObject(id)
```

However, I need to make a search by barcode rather than ID - need a pointer in the right direction here.

The barcodes field is an array that can contain one or more barcode numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a search with [`filters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/) on the barcodes attributes. The `filters`  parameter supports multiple format, numeric values included. It does not matter if the attribute hold a single or multiple (an array) values. Here is an example with the JavaScript client:

```
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const client = algoliasearch('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_API_KEY');
const index = client.initIndex('YOUR_INDEX_NAME');

index
  .search({
    filters: 'barcodes = YOUR_BARCODE_VALUE',
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.hits);
  });
```

---

The above example assumes that your records have a structure like this one:

```
{
  "barcodes": [10, 20, 30]
}
```